# Function with strict arguments

Tags: haskell

A corrected quiz in my textbook is asking me how many of `f`'s arguments are strict, `f` being:

```
f x 0 z = x == z
f x y z = x
```

My initial thought was that all of `f`'s arguments are to be considered strict, since `y` is being evaluated to check if its equal to `0`, and `x` and `z` are compared to see that they're both equal.
And yet the answer is that only `x` and `y` are strict.

Any clues as to why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, you need a very precise definition of "strict" in order for this to make sense. A function `f` is strict iff evaluating `f x` to whnf causes `x` to be evaluated to whnf. The interaction this has with currying is a bit awkward, and I'm going to ignore some of the potential weirdness that introduces.

Assuming the type here is `f :: Bool -> Int -> Bool -> Bool` your analysis of the behavior wrt `y` is correct - evaluating `f x y z` to whnf will always require evaluating `y` to determine which equation to choose. As that is the only factor determining which equation to use, we have to split the analysis for `x` and `z`. In the first equation, evaluating the result to whnf results in both `x` and `z` being evaluated. In the second equation, evaluating the result to whnf results in evaluating `x` to whnf.

Since `x` is evaluated in both branches, this function is strict in `x`. This is a little bit amusing - it's strict in the way `id` is strict. But that's still valid! `z`, however, is a different story. Only one of the branches causes `z` to be evaluated, so it's not evaluated strictly - it's only evaluated on demand. Usually we talk about this happening where evaluation is guarded behind a constructor or when a function is applied and the result isn't evaluated, but being conditionally evaluated is sufficient. `f True 1 undefined` evaluates to `True`. If `f` was strict in `z`, that would have to evaluate to `undefined`.

Answer (score 8):

It turns out that whether `f` is strict in its second argument depends on what type it gets resolved to.

Here's proof:

```
data ModOne = Zero
instance Eq ModOne where
    _ == _ = True -- after all, they're both Zero, right?
instance Num ModOne -- the method implementations literally don't matter

f x 0 z = x == z
f x y z = x
```

Now in ghci:

```
> f True (undefined :: ModOne) True
True
> f True (undefined :: Int) True
*** Exception: Prelude.undefined
```

And, in a related way, whether `f` is strict in its third argument depends on what values you pick for the first two. Proof, again:

```
> f True 1 undefined
True
> f True 0 undefined
*** Exception: Prelude.undefined
```

So, there isn't really a simple answer to this question! `f` is definitely strict in its first argument; but the other two are conditionally one or the other depending on circumstances.

Comment: Nice example! Presumably this indicates that pattern matching for instances of `Num` actually uses `Eq` under the covers? (`Eq` is a superclass of `Num` so I guess this wouldn't be crazy.) Is this behaviour specified in the Haskell report somewhere or is it just how GHC chooses to do it?

Comment: @RobinZigmond Yes, it uses `(==)` under the covers. That behavior is specified [here](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-600003.17.2).